# Differential equation $k^{n-2} D^2 f(u) = D^2 f(k u)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align}
k^{r-2} D^2 f( u) =   D^2 f(k u), \forall k \in (0, b), u \in S
\end{align} 
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is some invertible matrix, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is some non-zero vector,  $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is some open set.  Here $D^2$ denotes the Hessian matrix.   Suppose that $D^2 f( u)$ is invertible.

Question: How to characterize all $f$'s that satisfy this equation?

For example, for $n=1$  fixing $u=c$  and setting $f(u)=a^{-1}$ we have that 
\begin{align}
k^{n-2}   =  a  f^{''}(k c), \forall k \in (0, b).
\end{align}

So, the solution is given by 
\begin{align}
f(k)= c_1k^n+c_2k+c_3
\end{align}

Comment: Did you really want to have the same $D^2 f(ku)$ on both sides?

Comment: @RobertIsrael No. Sorry, that was a mistake. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is any smooth function on the unit sphere $S$ in $\mathbb R^n$, we can extend it to a function on $\mathbb R^n \backslash \{0\}$ that is homogeneous of order $r$ by $f(su) = s^r f(u)$.   Its Hessian will then be homogeneous of order $r-2$.  A function that has the same Hessian will be obtained from that by adding arbitrary constant and linear terms.

Comment: A have a few questions. 1) What do you mean by a smooth function?  Infinitely differentiable?

Comment: In this case twice differentiable should be enough.

Comment: I am not sure why the answer got down vote.   Ok. I have another question.  2) What do you mean by homogenous function?